# For Loop alternating printf

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, printf, alternating

I have this program where I'm prompting the user for a number, this number will be the number of line the message prints in the output. However, every even line I am to print the message("Hello") and every odd message I am to print("Hello Again!") and I'm not sure how to go about doing it. Here is what I've got so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int lines;
    int i;

    printf("How many times would you like me to repeat it?\n");
    scanf("%d", &lines);

    for (i=0;i<=lines;i++)
    {
        if (lines%i=0){
            printf("Hello!\n");
        } 
        else {
            printf("Hello Again!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try `if(i % 2 == 0)` in you loop to distinguish between odd & even count.

Comment: Your braces are mismatched, and the indentation (and spacing between lines) is all over the place. The code won't even compile as-is; please correct that.

Comment: In your `for` loop, change the `<= lines` into `< lines`, otherwise the loop will actually execute `lines` + 1 times.

Comment: always check the returned value from scanf() to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Is the first line of output an odd line (requiring Hello Again!) or an even line (requiring Hello)?  At the moment, you are treating it (or trying to treat it) as if it is an even line rather than an odd line.  However, it also seems odd to print Hello Again first, so your treatment is probably correct, even if the description of the problem isn't quite as accurate as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
int main()
{
    int lines;
    int i;
    printf("How many times would you like me to repeat it?\n");
    scanf("%d", &lines);
    for (i=0;i<lines;i++)
    {
        if (i%2 == 0){
            printf("Hello!\n");
        } 
        else {
            printf("Hello Again!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You have to take modulus by 2 to check even or odd and check the condition with the conditional operator "==" not with the assignment operator "="

Also give the return statement at the end of the main function.

Comment: the first pass needs to have 'i' be 0 so the first line outputs 'hello'.  suggest: 'for( i = 0; i<lines; i++ }'

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for notifying the mistake. UPDATED the code!